# Error adding field SolrJ Tika

Tags: java, solr, solrj, apache-tika

I am creating an application to index tables from a huge database. After indexing more then 10k records I receive an errror adding field in 1 column.

Here is error from solr logs:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR:
[doc=fd7c66bb-e92d-4465-bc86-f0545be6ceab] Error adding field
'FAT_RESULT_NUM'='0.5' msg=For input string: "0.5" 
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:176)
at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:83)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:237)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:163)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:328)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
```

I don't know why I don't have any errors in small part of rows.

Comment: Maybe the schema mapping for your table is wrong, because the error pointed is that you are trying to assign a string where it should have a float number. Try to change the solr table schema to receive a float instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

User **"float"** as the fieldType for the field "FAT_RESULT_NUM" in your schema.xml

If you want achieve faster range queries, consider using **"tfloat"** types